# TFS Continuous Integration and Deployment

Tags: tfs, msbuild

I have an web project Project A and a library Project B.
Project B is being built into Project A\Plugins.

The Problem is when Project A is being built via CI Project B isn't deployed with Project A. MSBuild params in CI are:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\" /t:ProjectA
```

I added the following piece of code into Project A.csproj to deploy Project B with A:

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectsToBuild Include="..\..\Plugins\**\*ProjectB*proj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="Plugin" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Message Text="Building Plugins" Importance="High" />
    <MSBuild Projects="@(ProjectsToBuild)" ContinueOnError="false" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration)">
      <Output ItemName="OutputFiles" TaskParameter="TargetOutputs" />
    </MSBuild>

    <CallTarget Targets="CopyPlugins"/>
  </Target>


    <PropertyGroup>
        <PluginDirectory>Plugins</PluginDirectory>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Target Name="CopyPlugins">
        <Message Text="Copying plugins to $(_PackageTempDir)\Plugins\ ($(ProjectDir)$(PluginDirectory))" Importance="high" />
        <CreateItem Include="$(ProjectDir)$(PluginDirectory)\**\*.*">
            <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="PluginFiles" />
        </CreateItem>
        <Copy DestinationFolder="$(_PackageTempDir)\Plugins\" SourceFiles="@(PluginFiles)" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
    </Target>
```

In the log executing order seems fine (Copy after Build), but after being deployed the Plugin folder doesn't exist on the target server.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't have a .sln (solution) that contains both ProjectA and ProjectB and ProjectA references ProjectB "by project" (in Visual Studio)?  This would make things easier.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Do you use XAML build or tasks based build? Do you check in the Plugin folder? Please login the build agent machine, and use MSBuild command line to build your project manually to see what result will you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files need to be included in the project. Since the files are generated dynamically, you can add this code to project file (e.g. XX.csproj)

```
  <Content Include="plugin\**\*.*" />
```

Comment: Thanks! Working like a charm! :)

Answer (score 0):

From your description, you would need to check in Project A\Plugins folder into TFS. But it's not suggested.

We suggest you make a project reference in the same solution or create NuGet for package management. It's recommended to [build a nuget package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package) for Project B, and [publish this Nuget package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/publish-a-package), then [restore the library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore) to Project A when you build it.